# HTML5 Canvas: Create tooltip on customized drawing

Tags: html5-canvas, flot

I am using [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) to plot images for our project. For pre-defined shapes like `line`, `pie`, I can add tooltip through [`flot.tooltip`](https://github.com/krzysu/flot.tooltip).

However, we have some images that are drawn through Html5 canvas API, such as [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_first). I would like to add a tooltip for the red rectangle and another tooltip for the blank area. Any library to make it work?

Comment: Are you drawing your images on top of a flot graph?

Comment: For this case, no `Flot`, i.e., no code like `$.plot()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With canvas there isn't a good way to detect when the mouse hovers over a particular drawn item; it's just a buffer, with no idea of what operations were used to draw into it.  Flot's own hover detection has no concept of what was drawn on the canvas; it just knows that, e.g. the pie starts at a particular point and extend outwards a certain number of pixels.

So no matter what, you will have to write a function that accepts a mouse event, examines whatever data you used to draw the image, and decides what that corresponds to.

Where Flot could help is in providing a way to override the built-in hover function with your own; then the tooltip plugin would simply work with your function.  Since you can't currently do that, you have a choice of a) modifying the tooltip plugin to use your function, or b) registering your own mousemove listener on the overlay element, which then generates 'fake' plothover events for the tooltip plugin to consume.